# Call to grep in command substitution fails

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to make a grep call in a command substitution in bash like so:

```
status=$(dpkg -s elasticsearch | grep "Status")
```

But when I run this in a script called `elk.sh`, I get the following output:

```
./elk.sh: 47: ./elk.sh:  grep: not found
```

It seems that when I use command substitutions, grep is not found. But when I call it normaly in my script, it is working as usual.

Do you have any idea of what could be wrong?

**EDIT:** as my code is not sensitive, I am sharing it here, since it may help you to understand what is wrong.

Note that `file elk.sh` returns:

```
elk.sh: POSIX shell script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

pInfo() {
    if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Invalid arguments: pInfo needs one string as argument."
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "\033[32m[INFO]\033[0m $1"
}

pError() {
    if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Invalid arguments: pError needs one string as arguments."
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "\033[31m[ERROR]\033[0m $1"
}

install_elk() {
    wget "https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.4.2.deb" -q --show-progress
    sudo dpkg -i "elasticsearch-6.4.2.deb"
    sudo apt-get install -f
    sudo rm -rRf "elasticsearch-6.4.2.deb"
}

which grep
echo $PATH
pInfo "Verifying ElasticSearch installation."
status=$(dpkg -s elasticsearch | grep Status)
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] || [ -z "$status" ]; then
    pError "ElasticSearch is not installed."
    pInfo "Start the installation ? (y/n)"
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" != "y" ] && [ "$answer" != "n" ]; then
        pError "Invalid answer. Just type 'y' (yes) or 'n' (no)."
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ "$answer" = "y" ]; then
        pInfo "Installing ElasticSearch..."
        install_elk
    else
        pInfo "Not installing ElasticSearch."
        exit 2
    fi
fi

pInfo "ElasticSearch installed."

ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "elasticsearch" > /dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then
    pInfo "ElasticSearch not running. Starting..."
    if [ ! -z "$(ps -p 1 | grep "systemd")" ]; then
        pInfo "System running systemd."
        sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
    else
        pInfo "System running init."
        sudo -i service elasticsearch start
    fi
fi

pInfo "ElasticSearch started."

exit 0
```

A call to `elk.sh` gives the following output:

```
$ ./elk.sh
/bin/grep
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
[INFO] Verifying ElasticSearch installation
[INFO] ElasticSearch installed
./elk.sh: 49: ./elk.sh:  grep: not found
[INFO] ElasticSearch not running. Starting...
[INFO] System running systemd.
[INFO] ElasticSearch started.
```

**EDIT**: I found the issue: rewriting the line like so:

```
status=$(dpkg -s elasticsearch |grep "Status")
```

makes the commands works just fine. I just needed to remove the whitespace between the pipe and the grep command.

Comment: can you add `which grep` before this command ?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of `echo $PATH` from the script as well?

Comment: `which grep` returns `/bin/grep` and `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: @Louis'LYRO'Dupont: You should try `echo $PATH` inside the script. If that also looks normal, then I suspect some encoding issue with your script. Try `file elk.sh` and/or upload a minimal copy to e.g. pastebin

Comment: @Thor you have the return value of `echo $PATH` right above.

Comment: @Louis'LYRO'Dupont: How about my other suggestions

Comment: @Thor I just added my code, since it is not sensitive.

Comment: `ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "elasticsearch >/dev/null; if [ "$? ... "` Can't you just `if ! pgrep elasticsearch 2>/dev/null; then`?

Comment: Surely, but that is not helping with my main issue here. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: The script is fine, you probably have some encoding issue